# Killing a hive process does not kill hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop, hive

I just discovered that killing a hive process does not kill the corresponding hadoop jobs.
I had to issue the `hadoop job -kill` command and drop the table by hand.
Is there a way to automate this: i.e., if a hive job is killed, all the hadoop jobs it spawned should be killed too (and the intermediate tables dropped)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of such a mechanism and have been doing precisely as you mention to do hadoop job -kill on the M/R job. That should only be required of the current stage of the hive job: the succeeding stages would not be launched.